# Rewind segue doesn’t trigger viewdidappear

Tags: swift, xcode, segue, viewdidappear

As the title goes, I have 2 view controllers connected by 2 buttons. On the first view controller, it modally segues to the second view controller via a button. On the second view controller, there is a button that updates a global variable, and another button that rewinds back to the original view controller. 
On the first view controller in my ‘ viewdidappear’ function, is an update of a label determined by a variable ( the same global variable changed in the second view controller ). 
When the second view rewinds back from the second one, it’s as if the viewdidappear function didn’t run at all, and the label did not update. 
Weirdly in my program there is a 3rd view controller that rewinds back to the first one, and had no problems what so ever updating labels in its viewdidappear function.

If anyone can shine some light on what is happening, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how are you presenting the 2nd and 3rd viewControllers and how you are doing the rewind segues?

Comment: From the 1st view controller to the second and third is a moral segue made by click and drag in UI builder. The rewind segues are done by clicking and dragging the button to the exit symbol and selecting the return view controller.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't because the previous view is already in the stack. You can try push instead of present modaly. Otherwise update the label in prepareforsegue funtion.

Comment: alright ill give the prepareforsegue a go. Don't know whether it's worth noting, but the 3rd working rewind is default view controller, but the 2nd is one that presents over the top of the first with a blur effect.